# Result involving right and left eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $x$ and $y$ be unit vectors in the Euclidean norm. Define $s(\lambda) = |y^Hx|$, where $Ax=\lambda x$   and $  y^HA=\lambda y^H$. Here $\lambda$  is a simple eigenvalue (an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity $1$). I would like to prove $s(\lambda) \leq 1$ and $s(\lambda)\neq 0$. I tried the following and gave up after that.

$$Ax=\lambda x $$
Premultiply by $y^H$
$$\begin{align*}
y^HAx &= \lambda y^Hx \\ y^HAx &= \lambda y^H I x
\end{align*}$$
Taking norm on both sides,
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\lambda} \|y^HAx\| &= \|y^H I x \| \\
\frac{1}{\lambda} \|y^HAx\| &= |y^Hx| 
\end{align*}$$

Can anyone  help me how to proceed after this?
(Similar question, with a matrix free proof here:[Proving that two right and left eigenvectors are not orthogonal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794520/proving-that-two-right-and-left-eigenvectors-are-not-orthogonal/794603?noredirect=1#comment1705683_794603))

Comment: $s(\lambda)\le1$ is immediate from the fact that $x$ and $y$ are unit vectors; it has nothing to do with them being eigenvectors of $A$. So you only need to show $s(\lambda)\neq0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt, you wrote $\frac1\lambda$, which is not a valid fraction if $\lambda=0$. Also, you haven't made use of the fact that $\lambda$ is a simple eigenvalue. Perhaps you should try another approach. For instance, assume that $x$ is a unit vector. If $U$ is a unitary matrix with $x$ as its first column (i.e. $U(1,0,\ldots,0)^\top = x$), then
$$
A = U
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda&v^\top\\
0&B
\end{pmatrix}
U^\ast = U\widehat{A}U^\ast \textrm{ (say)}
$$
for some vector $v$ and some matrix $B$. Since $U$ is unitary, eigenvalues, algebraic/geometric multiplicities of eigenvalues as well as orthogonality of vectors are preserved. Yet it is easier to make your argument by considering $\widehat{A}$. For example, that $\lambda$ is a simple eigenvalue means $B-\lambda I$ is invertible.